# Bosch Video streaming to web page

Tags: video-streaming, activex, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I have about 10 Bosch `IP` Cameras and I am trying use camera's `ActiveX` control to stream Camera video to a web page.
Any idea of how to use the `ActiveX` control to achieve this?

Comment: Most IP cameras are using RTSP, but I don't know what model of camera you have.

Comment: It's been some time since you asked, did you ever manage to solve this? I am in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating an ActiveX control using VB6 with the help of SDK provided by my client(BOSH camera integrator)

SDK has VB6 implementations to stream live videos of cameras.

I do not provide any VB6 code implementation here as my solution is specific to my integrator SDK.

Answer (score 0):

this may be off topic but in case anyone needs this, I have a C library based on RCP Plus version 3.0 specification [here](https://github.com/hawell/rcpplus)